# Deploy MEAN stack app in a subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js, angular

I'm trying to host a node app on www.domain.com/nodeapp. I've already got www.domain.com website hosted on apache server. I've created a reverse proxy in apache configuration.

```
ProxyPass /nodeapp http://localhost:3100/nodeapp
ProxyPassReverse /nodeapp http://localhost:3100/nodeapp
```

This is MEAN app's 
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndnug.png)
And below is my node app.js file where I'm linking my angular app in dist folder (which I built using `ng build --prod`)

```
app.use("/api/posts", postsRoutes);
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/client", clientRoutes);

app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "angular")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "angular", "index.html"));
});

module.exports = app;
```

When I run the node server.js file on port 3000. Only the index.html loads and other static files throws an 404.

I tired then adding an empty base-href `ng build --prod --base href` while building the angular app which loaded the app with static resources properly but when I navigate in angular app like `www.domain.com/nodeapp/auth/login` directly in the URL the path of the static file shows `www.domain.com/nodeapp/auth/login/style.css` which is obviously incorrect. 
The API links for e.g. (`http://localhost:3100/api/posts`) doesn't work when accessed using Reverse proxy.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any working guide where a MEAN app is hosted along side an apache server?

Comment: What is an example of a URL that got a 404?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It shows www.domain.com/style.234234234242.css for angular app instead of www.domain.com/nodeapp/style.234234234242.css